# Translation of very old tombstone

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, inscription

I'm trying to figure out writing on one very old tombstone that I found near church.
The text has some abbreviations  so I'm having hard time figuring out which word is being hidden behind abbreviations.
For now I know that lady in question is Elisabeth Judith and the guy in questions is John Logmagi from Dubrovnik.

Was this tombstone made by him for the Elisabeth or vice versa?
Any help is appreciated.
The tombstone itself is already missing parts of the writing due to age but I managed to dig up the text from one  local book ( unfortunately it doesn't have translation)

[image: inscription][image: photo]

Comment: How well do you understand Croatian? "Retoricar Andreas Paulus Logmagi, sin dubrovackog plemica Ivana Logmagi"

Comment: The book "Spomenici kotara Krapina i Zlatar " (Szabo 1914) https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/14423848.pdf

Comment: Do I understand the quote above in Croatian (or Serbo-Croatian?) correctly, "Andreas Paulus Logmagi, son of a nobleman Ivan Logmagi from Dubrovnik, who graduated from the Jesuit University in Graz, Austria"? ("Retoricar Andreas Paulus Logmagi, sin dubrovackog plemica Ivana Logmagi, bio je upisan u matrikule isusovačkog sveučilišta u Grazu (Austrija)"

Comment: and a very interesting document here http://www.rodoslovlje.hr/savjeti/najstarija-prezimena-radoboj

Comment: @AlexB. I understand it pretty well because I'm from Croatia :) And  that is exactly the book from which I took the screenshot with full text.

Comment: @AlexB. I forgot to answer your question, yes you understood it correctly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the inscription spelled out with all abbreviations expanded, ligatures spelled separately, and V spelled as U when it stands for a vowel:

> Nobilissimae ac Pientissimae
> Dominae Elisabethae Szuditth
> Consorti Dilectissimae Sibi
> Suisque Posteris Generosus
> Dominus Ioannes Logmagi de
> Raguseo Poni Curavit
> Anno 1620

The vocabulary is pretty standard apart from the names and *piens* instead of the more common *pius*.
Perhaps this variant was used to get a less awkward superlative.
Please bear in mind that Latin superlatives don't work quite like the English ones, and e.g. "most beloved" below should be understood as "dearly/very/highly beloved".
You can use superlatives like this in English as well, but it is far less common than in Latin.

This could be translated as follows, line by line:

> To the most noble and most dutiful
> lady Elisabeth Judith,
> to the most beloved partner to him
> and to his descendants, the generous
> mister John Logmagi
> of Dubrovnik had [this stone] put in place
> in the year 1620

Dubrovnik is known as *Ragusium* or *Ragusa* in Latin, and this inscription suggests the (unsurprising) variant *Raguseum*.

I am unsure whether *sibi suisque posteris* should modify *dilectissimae* or *generosus*.
Either Elisabeth was loved to John and his family or John was generous to himself and his family.
Either would make sense, but I chose the first option.

Comment: thank you for the  help with translation!

Comment: I think the superlatives can work he same even in English.  This is most interesting, most extraordinary...  "my most dutiful respect performed to Her Majesty..."

Comment: @VladimirF Indeed, a superlative can be used in English in this same fashion, but it is rarer. And non-native speakers might be unfamiliar with it, so I always want to warn about it.

Answer (score 5):

Elizabeth's name is in the dative case, so it was made for her. It translates to:

> To the noblest and [most pious](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/joll-2020-2015/html) lady Elisabeth Judith, his most delightful wife, for himself and his descendents the generous lord John Logmagi of Ragusa (mod. Dubrovnik) oversaw (this tombstone) to be erected in the year 1620.

Comment: Thank you for correction!

Answer (score 4):

> For the most noble and most pious Lady Elisabetha Szuditth, his most beloved wife, and for his descendants, the noble Lord Joannes Logmagi of Raguseum had this memorial placed in the year 1620.

The abbreviations mean *suis-que* ("and for his own"), *Dominus* ("the lord"), and *anno* ("in the year").

Comment: Whoa, tied again!

Comment: And you both beat me to it, but I chose to post instead of deleting.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!